# How do i run a function() once then toogle and make them run simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I would like to ask how do i "drawTable" only for once and toggle it? i dont wanna call my ajax everytime i click the element. When i clicked tableA, drawTable() took too long to load and tableA's class has already toogled first because i have another toggleSetting() function on my tableA's onclick, how can i make sure it changes at the same time?

```
$("#tableA").on("click", (function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Acc.ashx",
                    success: function (output) {
                        try {
                            output = JSON.parse(output);
                            DrawATable(output);
                        }
                        catch (ex) {
                            alert("error");
                            $('#tableA').empty();
                        }
                    }
                    , complete: function (data) {
                        isClicked = false;

                    }
                }).then($('#tableSAOnce').toggleClass('accordion accordion2'))
            }));
```

```
    function toggleSetting(setting, ctrl) {

        var stt = document.getElementById(setting);
        if (stt.style.display == 'none') {
            stt.style.display = '';
            ctrl.className = "accordion2";
        }
        else {
            stt.style.display = 'none';
            ctrl.className = "accordion";
        }           
    }
```

```
            <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="tableAOnce" class="accordion" onclick="toggleSetting('toggleA',this)">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">TableA</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="display:none;" id="toggleA" >
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tableA"></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a little bit hard to understand what you are trying to do exactly, but I think I have understood it now.

I changed classes and ids of your markup to make the jQuery code simpler. If you now click on `.accordion .accordion-toggler`, the element of `data-toggle` will be made visible by toggling the class `hide`. With each toggle, the code checks whether the table already has contents. If there is no content, the `doAjax` function is called. Then you have to change your `DrawATable` function as I described in the new function `drawTable`.

I hope this will help you.

```js
var $tableToggler = $('#tableToggle');

function onTogglerClick(event) {
  var $triggerElement = $(event.currentTarget);
  var $target = $($triggerElement.data('toggle'));

  if ($target.length) {
    $target.closest('.toggle-parent').toggleClass('hide');

    // check if indicator for contents exists
    if (!$triggerElement.hasClass('has-contents')) {
      doAjax($target);
    }
  }
}

function doAjax($target) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Acc.ashx",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output) {
      // you can simply use "dataType: 'json'", so your response is a json object
      // and then you don't need to try to parse the output into json
      drawTable($target, output);
    },
    error: function() {
      $target.empty();
    },
    /* complete: function(data) {
      // do you need this line anymore?
      // isClicked = false;
    } */
  });
}

function drawTable($target, content) {
  // example start
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  
  sb.append('<tr><td>' + content[0] + '</td></tr>');
  $target.html(sb.toString());
  // example end
  
  if ($target.children().length) {
    $target.addClass('has-contents');
  }
}

$tableToggler.on('click', '.accordion-toggler', onTogglerClick);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="tableToggle" class="accordion">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="accordion-toggler" data-toggle="#tableA">TableA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="accordion-toggler" data-toggle="#tableB">TableB</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toggle-parent hide">
    <td>
      <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tableA"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="toggle-parent hide">
    <td>
      <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tableB"></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you sir! sorry that i cant understand how $target works and what does target.length does? What if i have different tables and different drawTable functions such as drawTableA, drawTable B, etc.. ? how do i make sure how they toggle their each respective table toggles?

Comment: please check my answer above and questions too~ sorry to bother u this much

Comment: @LeeWyncent Could you perhaps add the content of your `DrawATable` function to your question? Then I could show how the code of the new `drawTable` function could look like. The `$target` is the reference to the table, so you could do something like this: `$target.html('<tr><td>1st row 1st field</td></tr>);`

Comment: function drawTableA($target, output) { //here?
  var general = output;
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("<table><tr><td>general[0]</td></tr></table>");
  //$('#tableA').empty().html(sb.toString());
  $target.html(sb.toString());

  if ($target.children().length) {
    $target.addClass('has-contents');
  }
}

something like this?

Comment: @LeeWyncent I've editet my answer with your questions. You can see the result in the `drawTable` function.

Comment: please check my new answer, i did it like ur code but it wont work :/ did i do it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("#tb1").on("click", function () {

            if (($("#tb2 tr").length) > 0) {
                $("#tb2").toggle();
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", url: "Test.ashx"
                    , success: function (output) {
                        try {
                            output = JSON.parse(output);
                            DrawTable(output);
                            
                        }
                        catch (ex) {
                            alert("error");
                            $('#tb2').empty();
                            
                        }
                    }
                    , complete: function (data) {
                        $("#tb2").show();
                    }
                })
            }
        });


        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="tb1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>TableA</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <table id="tb2"></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: You should really update your question instead of add multiple answers. Do not say "couldnt work", please be more explicit what does not work and what errors you got. You asked for a solution for jQuery (client side) and I gave you an answer. I can't tell you how to include it in your VS project (server side) now. You also included two different versions of jQuery, which inevitably leads to errors. You also have an unsemantic markup, maybe you can edit it when all problems are fixed.

Comment: @UfguFugullu sorry about it sir, but i managed to do it in this way, by referring to your code. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please do not forget to mark your answer to this question :)

Comment: @UfguFugullu so i just edit the way i did it into this answer? sorry im pretty new to this platform and i dont know the correct practice